# Python 3 Protocols - is it possible to require specific arguments in method, but allow extra arguments as well?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, typing

I am trying type hint a protocol to encompass a small variety of similar API interfaces.
I want to allow certain methods to be flexible and allow for extra arguments and keyword arguments, since different implementations have different 'bonus' args, but all of them share a common set of arguments at the first half of the signature.

This is awkward because I'm trying to write compatibility for some classes that I don't control directly, so I can't edit the implementation signatures.

```py
from typing import Protocol

class ExampleProtocol(Protocol):
    def test(self, important_arg:str, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class ExampleImplementation:
    def test(self, important_arg:str):
        pass

class ExampleImplementation2:
    def test(self, important_arg:str, unnessary_arg:bool):
        pass

implementation: ExampleProtocol = ExampleImplementation()
implementation2: ExampleProtocol = ExampleImplementation2()
```

Pylance gives me this:

```
"ExampleImplementation" is incompatible with protocol "ExampleProtocol"
    "test" is an incompatible type
      Type "(important_arg: str) -> None" cannot be assigned to type "(important_arg: str, *args: Unknown, **kwargs: Unknown) -> None"
        Parameter "**kwargs" has no corresponding parameter
```

Is it possible to type hint in this case, or do I need to just use Any instead of the protocol? Does python allow hinting "dynamic" signatures that have a few important arguments?

**EDIT**: It seems that this isn't possible, so the best solution I could come up with is to use the Callable type to at the very least indicate that a method with that name should exist, without enforcing any arguments, like so:

```py
class ExampleProtocol(Protocol):
    test: Callable
```

This seems to work and not give any errors on the two examples.

Comment: These are completely distinct, incompatible signatures. A protocol is supposed to define ways in which instances of the protocol can be used in compatible ways, but these signatures are incompatible.

Comment: curious, is this for `mypy` or something?

Comment: Currently using pylint, but I was hoping to annotate enough to give better error messages and autocompletion in IDE regardless of what you're using

Comment: Two implementations you provide are incompatible and cannot implement the same protocol (doesn't matter how you define it, except for one that doesn't involve `test` args definition). It is not possible to call neither `HypotheticalParent().test('foo')` nor `HypotheticalParent().test('foo', True)`. `ExampleImplementation2` should have `def test(self, important_arg: str, unnecessary_arg: bool = False)` to be compatible, and then `Protocol` can define just `def test(self, important_arg: str)`. This is what [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is about.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer here is 'no', mostly because your `ExampleImplementation` method `test` (or `ExampleImplementation2`) has a subset of the parameters allowed by `ExampleProtocol`. That is, there is some set of parameters that `ExampleProtocol` accepts that `ExampleImplementation` would break on - anything past that first argument.

Without knowing what you're trying to get at exactly, you're left with manually filtering the `*agrs` and `**kwargs` parameters for those that you care about. The former can be difficult because they're not named, they're only positional.

That said, the type-hint you're reaching for is `Optional`. It doesn't solve your problem on it's own, but it's a type that declares 'either this is None or it is of type x'. For instance:

```
def f(a: Optional[bool]) -> None:
    # a is either None or a boolean value
```

`Any` doesn't really do anything for you here, I think.

Comment: I think I was unclear - Any would be in place of the protocol itself, not one of the method arguments.